# sql: select only max, min, mid from another column, with the rest as null

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to create a new column in a table based on an existing column. In the example below, I want to select the max, min, and mid of "Amount" order by the "Sequence" number, partition by "Person"

Can anyone help? Thank you!

[image]

The data in comma delimited.

```
Person,Sequence,Amount
A,1,1908
A,2,3896
A,3,2726
A,4,4730
A,5,4174
A,6,3156
A,7,3360
A,8,2439
B,1,1768
B,2,1967
B,3,1841
B,4,1534
B,5,729
B,6,2434
B,7,3502
B,8,108
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using conditional aggregation.  You do need a bit more information to get the middle value:

```
select person, min(amount), max(amount)
       max(case when 2 * sequence in (cnt, cnt + 1) then amount end) as middle_val
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by person) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by person;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see, you want the rest as NULL -- not just the three values per person.  Then:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sequence in (1, floor(cnt / 2), maxseq) then amount
        end) as new_amount
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by person) as cnt,
             max(sequence) over (partition by person) as maxseq
      from t
     ) t;
```